# C++ Start a thread in Class A and .join in Class B

Tags: c++, multithreading

Given following example:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();

    static std::thread m_thread;

    void longRunning()
    {
        // long running task
    }

    void startThread()
    {
        std::thread m_thread(std::bind(&A::longRunning, this));
    }
};

class B
{
    B();
    ~B();

public:
    // this is the target function where the programm should block until the thread is finished
    void maxFunction()
    {
        std::thread m_thread;
        m_thread.join();
    }
};

// init the thread
class C
{
    C();
    ~C();

public:
    void init()
    {
        A instanceA;
        instanceA.startThread();
    }
};
```

My goal is to use `std::thead` to run a long running task in the background, until a given point where it should block the program. This given point lives in another class. If the task is done before this given point, then the thread should exit and the program shouldn't be interrupted (which is the goal and should mostly be the case).

The problem is, that the program crashes instantly. I also feel, that this shouldn't be solved like this.

Comment: I don't understand your example. The `m_thread` in `B::maxFunction` has no connection whatsoever to `A::m_thread`.

Comment: Rather check out promise and future

Comment: Explaining Nathan's comment: `std::thread m_thread(std::bind(&A::longRunning, this));` made a brand new `std::thread named `m_thread` that hid `static std::thread m_thread;`. Side note: `std::thread` is smart enough to not need the `std::bind`. `(&A::longRunning, this)` is sufficient.

Comment: Side note: This is risky as hell once the above bug is fixed. Make two `A`s. Call `startThread` on both of them. The second one replaces the first, probably before the first has finished running and tripping the call to `std::terminate` in [the destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

Comment: _"the program crashes instantly"_ - Most probably because of undefined behavior in a lot of places. You do not synchronize anything, so anything goes. Please show a [mre] if you need help.

Answer (score 2):

The `A` class is declaring a static `std::thread` member named `m_thread`, and the `A::startThread()` and `B::maxFunction()` methods are both declaring their own *local* `std::thread` variables also named `m_thread`.  The 3 `std::thread` objects are distinct and have no relation to each other.

The `std::thread` object being created in `A::startThread()` is destroyed immediately, and its destructor will throw a `std::terminate` exception because you did not call `join()` or `detach()` on it.

The `std::thread` object being created in `B::maxFunction()` is destroyed when the function exits, and although it is being `join()`'ed, `join()` will throw a `std::invalid_argument` exception because `joinable()` is false as you did not ask this `std::thread` object to start running any function.

With that said, you likely meant to do something more like this instead:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();

    static std::thread m_thread;

    void longRunning()
    {
        // long running task
    }

    void startThread()
    {
        m_thread = std::thread(&A::longRunning, this);
    }
};

class B
{
    B();
    ~B();

public:
    // this is the target function where the programm should block until the thread is finished
    void maxFunction()
    {
        A::m_thread.join();
    }
};

// init the thread
class C
{
    C();
    ~C();

public:
    void init()
    {
        A instanceA;
        instanceA.startThread();
    }
};

...

B instanceB;
instanceB.maxFunction(); // call only after A::startThread() has been called first
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm still unsure if this leads somehow to Undefined Behavior. Is there a way to improve this? Or is there even a better approach?

Comment: @complex1984 The only potential UB in my example would be if `longRunning()` were still running when the static `m_thread` is destroyed. Since `m_thread` is static, it won't be destroyed until the program is shutting down, and that is a bad time to be raising exceptions. AFAIK, everything else in this example has well-defined behavior. Now, whether or not this is the kind of code you should be using in the first place, that is a separate matter...